# INSERT/DELETE entire row vs UPDATE BOOL field?

Tags: mysql

My normalized DB has a table where a 1-N relationship exists for attributes related to the user. One of these attributes involves storing a yes/no binary status. This attribute is relatively frequently updated (TRUE to FALSE then back to TRUE) but also frequently retrieved.

Table

```
user_id (FK user table) | value_id (regular int) | yes_no (bool)
```

User has multiple variations of value_id but these are always retrieved as an entire set i.e. SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id=ID

I'm thinking a bulk SELECT like that would benefit from lesser rows to return if all the FALSE rows are deleted from the table instead of being updated.

However, I understand that updating a single field would definitely also be less taxing than multiple INSERT/DELETE.

Thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Update, but exclude false values from your select, if you only need true ones returned?

Comment: If you delete the rows with `yes_no=FALSE`, you'll lose all their values. Are the values unimportant in this case?

Comment: I think he means that it is possible only store record for 'true' value. So if no record (user_id, value_id, 1) -- it means 'no' for the value with value_id.

Answer (score 0):

Delete/insert will require from MySQL to rebuild indexes and update statistics (you have FKs == indexes).
If you have many records in the table and changing data often, this would be expensive.

Comment: If I do a ```SELECT WHERE yes_no=FALSE``` for the update method, I would also need to build an index on the yes_no field which would also get updated often as well right?

Comment: Sure, if you index the yes_no column it will require rebuilding any way. However, other indexes will not require rebuilding. In case you have composite index (user_id, yes_no) it will be used for FK and still require rebuilding on update. However, it will not be used in query you just mentioned. While answering, I just pointed out the you may consider a bit of thinking for the 'index rebuildng' (as you asked for 'thoughts')